# Need for break in while loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I am writing a loop whereby if a queue is not empty, the loop will run, and I was just wondering if there was a need to include a `break` at the end of the loop. Essentially each loop should run for every single element in the queue until the queue is empty.

So which of the following should it be - I just don't know if there is a *right* thing to do.

```
while (1)
{

    /*process message from incoming queue*/
    if (!msgs_inc.empty())
    {
        /*categorise incoming message into global map of outgoing messages*/
        msgInfo current_msg = incMsgClassification(msgs_inc.front());
        msgs_inc.pop();

        clients_msg[current_msg.destID][current_msg.priorityLevel].push(current_msg);
    }
}
```

or

```
while (1)
{
    //Sleep(50000);
    //cout << "success" << endl;

    /*process message from incoming queue*/
    if (!msgs_inc.empty())
    {
        /*categorise incoming message into global map of outgoing messages*/
        msgInfo current_msg = incMsgClassification(msgs_inc.front());
        msgs_inc.pop();

        clients_msg[current_msg.destID][current_msg.priorityLevel].push(current_msg);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if isn't a loop, it is a conditional

Comment: adding a `break` would terminate your `while` loop, is that what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is more cleanly written as ..

```
while (!msgs_inc.empty()) // loop as long as queue still has elements
{    
    /*process message from incoming queue*/
    /*categorise incoming message into global map of outgoing messages*/
    msgInfo current_msg = incMsgClassification(msgs_inc.front());
    msgs_inc.pop();

    clients_msg[current_msg.destID][current_msg.priorityLevel].push(current_msg);
}
```

Or perhaps

```
while(1) {//infinite loop
    while (!msgs_inc.empty()) // loop as long as queue still has elements
    {    
        /*process message from incoming queue*/
        /*categorise incoming message into global map of outgoing messages*/
        msgInfo current_msg = incMsgClassification(msgs_inc.front());
        msgs_inc.pop();

        clients_msg[current_msg.destID][current_msg.priorityLevel].push(current_msg);
    }
}
```

This is more relevant if this function is running on a seperate thread, and is the only piece of code running on that thread.

Comment: it (the 2nd) is indeed what I needed, thank you! don't know why I figured an `if` instead of a `while`.